# My code doesn't mantain the value in future operations

Tags: javascript

It is a simple homebanking, made with javascript. It works well if I do a first operation, but then if I perform another operation it doesn't  maintain the value of the previous one

I tried to modify the functions that add (sumaDinero) and subtract (restDinero) the money in the account but I think they are fine. I can't see where the problem is

```
let saldoCuenta = 3000;

const sumaDinero = (dinero) => {
    let nuevoSaldo = saldoCuenta + dinero;
    return nuevoSaldo;
}

const restDinero = (dinero) => {
   let  nuevoSaldo = saldoCuenta - dinero;
    return  nuevoSaldo;
}

const extraerDinero = (dinero) => {
    let ingreso = prompt("Ingrese la cantidad de dinero que desea extraer");
    dinero = parseInt(ingreso);
    let valorFinal = restDinero(dinero);

    if ((dinero % 100 == 0) && (dinero <= saldoCuenta)) {
        alert(`Su saldo anterior es de: $ ${saldoCuenta}  \nEl monto de su extracción es de: $ ${ingreso}
         \nSu saldo actual es de: $ ${valorFinal}`);
        nuevoValorEnCuenta = document.getElementById("saldo-cuenta").innerHTML = `$ ${valorFinal}`;
    } else if ((dinero <= saldoCuenta) && (dinero % 100 !== 0)) {
        alert(`Sólo puedes extraer billetes de $100`);
    } else if ((isNaN(ingreso) === true) || (ingreso == '0')) {
        alert(`El monto ingresado no es válido`);
    } else {
        alert(`No posee dinero suficiente para hacer esa extracción`);

    }
}
```

I need that the value that one operation throws, in this case extraerDinero()", be maintained when I perform another operation.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, show how these functions are used.

Comment: Hint: you need to update `saldoCuenta` with the correct value.

Comment: var saldoCuenta, It is a variable that is given any value, in this case 3000. That is the initial amount in the account. Then there are the functions that add and extract money from the account (in this case of the initial $ 3000. When I want to extract, for example, $ 400, works well and returns the expected values, modifying the balance on the screen (which would be $ 2600). But then when I want to withdraw $ 600, makes that subtraction based on the initial balance that was $ 3000 and not based on the value of the balance in the last operation performed

Comment: You might want to assign the value of `valorFinal` to `saldoCuenta` at the end of `extraerDinero`. That way, when `extraerDinero` gets called again, you could work with `saldoCuenta`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let valorFinal = restDinero(dinero);
```

You are assigning the new balance to a new variable here. You need to update the global account balance instead:

```
saldoCuenta = restDinero(dinero);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That worked!! I was trying to do it with valorFinal  but it didn't make sense.

Comment: @ElizabethSabellaRosa This is what my hint in the comments to your question referred to. I suggest that you learn more about the difference between local and global variables to understand what was going on with your original code.

Answer (score 0):

You read from `saldoCuenta`, but you never write to it.

---

I think your code can be improved at a few places

1) You should do checks of values before you do anything with them. Your `if..else` logic is likely to fail at some point, instead move the checks to the front and end the execution early in case of an error

```
 // Do checks first:
  if(!isRightFormat) return;
  if(!isEnoughMoney) return;

  doRealAction();
```

2) Your functions, e.g. `restDinero` are wrong abstractions. The `restDinero` function is kinda useless as it provides no real functionality. On the other hand `extraerDinero` does *too much*, it mixes validations, operations and user interactions. Instead I'd write (1) utilities to validate and mutate the data, that throw errors if needed, and (2) functions for user interaction.

3) I'd encapsulate `saldoCuenta` as you want to make sure that this value doesn't get changed the wrong way, global variables are generally bad.

Here's how I'd write that:

```
  // The utilities for modification & validation
  const moneyStore = ((() => { // encapsulation through an IIFE
    let value = 3000; // This variable can only be accessed from the functions *here*, so the validations cannot be bypassed

    return {
      get value() { return value; }, // provide read-only access from the outside

      increase(amount) {
        if(!Number.isFinite(amount) || amount < 0) 
           throw new Error("Cannot add non-number to money");

       return value += amount; // return the updated value
      },

      decrease(amount) {
        if(!Number.isFinite(amount) || amount < 0) 
           throw new Error("Cannot add non-number to money");

        if(amount > value)
          throw new Error("Not enough money available");

        return value -= amount;
      },
   };
})();

function decreaseAmount() {
  const decreaseBy = parseInt(prompt("How much money do you wanna take?"), 10);
  if(decreaseBy % 100 !== 0) {
    alert("The value must be a multiple of 100");
    return;
  }

  try {
    moneyStore.decrease(decreaseBy);
    alert(`Returned ${decreaseBy}, current amount is ${moneyStore.value}`);
  } catch(error) {
    alert(`Could not return money because ${error.message}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your observation. I understand what you say, my project is for beginners. The place where I study didn't mention any of the corrections you make, so your comment is very useful for me. I'll put into practice!

Comment: During your course you will probably see some of the techniques I used ... it might be a but early then to adopt the code in the answer, but maybe somewhen it might be worth checking it again ... glad to have helped :)